# Google sheets - not working format date from number. How to fix?

Tags: date, google-sheets, format

Couldn't change date format from numners (1680433618, 1680433638, 1680590143) to another format (dd.mm.yyyy).
I changed locales, time zone and language
Link to my sheet -
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QAlUowTMS8ZFnR2MS41FBQSRjopYRkRz3rtt0RKs3xc/edit?usp=sharing
Pleas help

I changed locales, time zone and language
I tried use TEXT function - no resault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with [epochtodate()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13193461):

```
=epochtodate(A2)
```

[image]